# store image as blob into sqlite success, but can't read it?

Tags: sqlite, rust

Update:

add my `Cargo.toml` in case needed:

```ini
serde = { version = "1.0.117", default-features = false }
serde_json = "1.0.66"
sql-builder = "3.1"
sqlite = "0.26.0"
```

---

Update:

i did @cdhowie says on comment, add `println!("{:?}", row[2].kind());`, it's print `String`.

it's the way i store blob wrong, shouldn't use `serde_json::to_string` or something?

---

OP:

i writed a demo to learn sqlite and rust, here the code:

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::{Read, Write}};

use sql_builder::{quote, SqlBuilder};
use sqlite::Connection;
fn main() {
    // create sqlite databases on ./tmp/sqlite.db
    let conn = Connection::open("./tmp/sqlite.db").unwrap();

    // create table
    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS icon (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT,
            content BLOB,
            used STRING
        )",
    )
    .unwrap();

    // read image file from disk and store to sqlite as blob
    let mut file = File::open("./tmp/in.jpg").unwrap();
    let mut contents = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut contents).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", contents);

    // build sql query
    let sql = SqlBuilder::insert_into("icon")
    .fields(&["name", "content", "used"])
        .values(&[
            quote(serde_json::to_string("in").unwrap()),
            quote(serde_json::to_string(&contents).unwrap()),
            quote(serde_json::to_string("1").unwrap()),
        ])
        .sql().unwrap();

    // execute query
    conn.execute(&sql).unwrap();

    // read image file from sqlite and store to disk
    let mut builder = SqlBuilder::select_from("icon");
        builder.field("id");
        builder.field("name");
        builder.field("content");
        builder.field("used");
    let stmt = conn.prepare(&builder.sql().unwrap()).unwrap();

    let mut cursor = stmt.into_cursor();
    let row = cursor.next().unwrap().unwrap();
    let id = row[0].as_integer().unwrap();
    let name = row[1].as_string().unwrap();
    let content = row[2].as_binary().unwrap(); // src/main.rs:51:38
    let used = row[3].as_string().unwrap();

    println!("{} {} {}", id, name, used);

    let mut file = File::create("./tmp/out.jpg").unwrap();
    file.write_all(content).unwrap();
}
```

when i run this code, will got error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:51:38
```

but where i check the `sqlite.db` file, it shows:

[image: vscode sqlite viewer]

[image: dbeaver]

seems file stored success. but how can i fix the code make read form sqlite and store to disk work?

if you guys need more info, please let me know. :)

Comment: Might be good to point out line 51 somehow so it's easier to tell where the panic is coming from.

Comment: My suggesting would be to write out the value of `row[2].kind()`, as it might be detecting it as something else, like a string.

Comment: @cdhowie hi, i think you are right, the row[2] be detecting it as String, i updated this question.

Comment: Note that column types in SQLite do not restrict data; you can store `text` data in an `int` column! You probably need to tell the SQL generator that the data is binary by handing it a `Vec<u8>` instead of a `String` -- try replacing `serde_json::to_string(&contents)` with `serde_json::to_string(&contents).into_bytes()` and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @cdhowie rust says `Vec<u8> doesn't implement std::fmt::Display` , `sql_builder::SqlBuilder` `pub fn values<S>(&mut self, values: &[S]) -> &mut Self` require `S: ToString`.

Comment: Huh... then you may need an alternative way to build the statement that casts it as the correct data type. Anyway, it seems like a defect if the SQL statement builder can't handle binary data.

Comment: Also, note that quote-based SQL generation is fraught with pitfalls; it's still possible to perform SQL injection on many databases because different DBs have different quoting rules, which may even depend on things like the locale or default collation of the connection. I would strongly advise you to avoid using SQL statement generation like this unless it generates prepared statements directly against the database.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks you sir, i'll try look deep the SqlBuilder doc. and see other SQL generation lib. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can fix the issue now, but this may not be the best solution.

```rust
// ...
let content = row[2].as_string().unwrap();
// ...

// ...
let content: Vec<u8> = serde_json::from_str(&content).unwrap();
file.write_all(&content).unwrap();
// ...
```

also, I may have found a better one SQL generation lib, called `diesel`.

Maybe as I keep learning, I might find a better, more elegant way. Anyway, it's working now. :)